# Jquery array splice changes the previously declared array too

Tags: jquery, arrays, splice

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $new_questions = [1,2,3,4,5];
    var $new_questions2 = $new_questions;
    
    $new_questions.splice(2, 2);
    
    $("#array_values_1").html($new_questions.toString());
    $("#array_values_2").html($new_questions2.toString());
});
```

I need to preserver the $new_questions2 variable. But both arrays are changed when using splice.

https://jsfiddle.net/uoncyber/q51kjmny/5/

Comment: Try this to get a better understanding of how objects point to each other while values create copies:  `var q = [1,2,3,4,5];
var q2 = q;
q2[0] = 9;
console.log(q)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var $new_questions2 = $new_questions` to `var $new_questions2 = $new_questions.slice()`